# Cannot find CFBundleSupportedPlatforms. App Store Upload Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "*****". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - A nested bundle contains simulator platform listed in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Info.plist key.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I received this email after I uploaded my app to the store. I know there are similar questions about this problem online and they say to replace iPhoneSimulator with iPhoneOS.

```
<key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
<array>
<string>iPhoneSimulator</string>
</array>
```

However I cannot find CFBundleSupportedPlatforms in my project, so I cannot fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't apple tell you how to fix this??

Comment: Nope. I have looked everywhere online. Everyone says to change iPhoneSimulator to "iPhoneOS" in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms. But I cannot find this in any of the info.plist's.....annoying error.

Comment: no idea, perhaps create the CFBundleSupportedxx file / key yourself?

Comment: ps, this didn't have anything to do with swift or spritekit, so I removed those tags :( but added in the app-store tag!! =}

Comment: I tried to add it myself. I created CFBundleSupportedPlatforms in the info.plist as a dictionary, then added the string "iPhoneOS". Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this issue is due to some of the frameworks or libraries built for iphonesimulator/macos. The best way to check that is to go through all your libraries or those that were recently added to confirm the architecture they are build for using the 'lipo' tool.

```
lipo -info frameworkexecutableorlib

Architectures in the fat file: frameworkexecutableorlib are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Usually the build process can strip unsupported architectures when archiving/exporting the application.